# AngularJS TypeError: d is undefined - Firefox, angular-route.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined - Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, requirejs

I'm working on a AngularJS based responsive single page web application displaying some data and I have a problem probably connected with RequireJS. I recieve `d is undefined` while using Firefox and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined`, but after refreshing the Chrome everything looks ok (doesn't work with Firefox). Here is the code:

RequireJS config:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'js',
paths: {
    angular: [
    'lib/angular.min',
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min'
    ],
    angularRoute: [
    'lib/angular-route.min',
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min'
    ]
}
});
```

script

```
define(['angular','angularRoute'], function($) {

var app = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"]) 
                 .config(function($routeProvider) { 
                    $routeProvider
                        .when("/home", { 
                            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                            controller: "homeController" 
                        })
                        .when("/repositories", {
                            templateUrl: "templates/repositories.html",
                            controller: "repositoriesController"
                        })
                        .when("/contributors", {
                            templateUrl: "templates/contributors.html",
                            controller: "contributorsController"
                        })
                        .otherwise({
                            redirectTo: "/home"
                        })
                 })
                 .controller("homeController", function($scope) {
                    $scope.headingOne = "App description";

                 })
                 .controller("repositoriesController", function($scope, $http, $log) {
                    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/x-formation/repos')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            $scope.gitHub = response.data;
                        })
                    $scope.headingTwo = "X-Formation public repositories";  
                    $scope.sortColumn = "forks_count";
                    $scope.reverseSort = true;

                    $scope.sortData = function(column)  {
                        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
                        $scope.sortColumn = column;
                    }

                    $scope.getSortClass = function (column) {
                        if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
                        return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up';
                        }
                    return '';
                    }
                 })
                 .controller("contributorsController", function($scope, $http) {
                    $http.get('http://cors.io/?u=https://www.x-formation.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/contributors.json')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            $scope.xFormationData = response.data;
                        })
                    $scope.headingThree = "Top contributors";   
                    $scope.sortColumn = "contributions";
                    $scope.reverseSort = true;

                    $scope.sortData = function(column)  {
                        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
                        $scope.sortColumn = column;
                    }

                    $scope.getSortClass = function (column) {
                        if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
                        return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up';
                        }
                    return '';
                    }
                 })

});
```

I've started recently and I feel like this is a little bit out of my league, but I'll have to know it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that stands out in your code is your require statement:

`define(['angular','angularRoute'], function($) {`

Instead of the `$` sign, you need to pass `angular`.

Also your require set up is missing some shim settings. Follow this article https://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/ and see if that solves your problem.